# Where to check for the blank result for the 'Automation Services Job Builder' in Spotfire using Send Email option

Tags: spotfire

I set up an automation service with 'Send Email' to attach couple of Visualization images to our users.

This report has a Prompt set up and when i normally open the report the data and Viz is displayed normally.

See the images attached to see the result i am getting.

I set another report an got the Viz image properly.

How should i check where the issue is since the report is opening fine but the blank image is there when i set up in Automation service.

I took the log from the Automation Services Log. It says that particular columns are missing but the same is available in the report and the report loads fine.Check the log below and let me know how to solve this issue:

```
2017-07-07 12:07:21,963 INFO  [Web Service-6532,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.WebService.Global: ##########################################
2017-07-07 12:07:21,994 INFO  [Web Service-6532,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.WebService.Global: Web Service Application starting
2017-07-07 12:07:21,994 INFO  [Web Service-6532,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.WebService.Global: Machine environment: Name=GBBWI138, OS Version=Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1, Is 64 bit OS=True, Processor count=8, .NET version=4.0.30319.36373.
2017-07-07 12:07:21,994 INFO  [Web Service-6532,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.WebService.Global: Process environment: Assembly version: 14.10.7525.5058, Runs as=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, Is 64 bit process=True.
2017-07-07 12:07:21,994 INFO  [Web Service-6532,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.WebService.Global: Web environment: Authentication mode=None, Impersonation enabled=False, Execution Timeout=00:10:00
2017-07-07 12:07:22,088 INFO  [Web Service-6532,7] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.WebService.JobExecutor: Launching asynchronous job (2).
2017-07-07 12:07:22,119 INFO  [Web Service-6532,7] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.WebService.JobExecutor: Asynchronous job 6722dfba-f649-430a-a1dc-a11504e89628 launched.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,525 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.Launcher.Program: *************
2017-07-07 12:07:22,572 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.Launcher.Program: Application Start
2017-07-07 12:07:22,572 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.Launcher.Program: Machine environment: Name=GBBWI138, OS Version=Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1, Is 64 bit OS=True, Processor count=8, .NET version=4.0.30319.36373.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,572 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.Launcher.Program: Process environment: Assembly version: 14.10.7525.5058, Runs as=NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, Is 64 bit process=True.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,603 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.Launcher.Program: User environment: Impersonation identity=138, Proxy user=, Use certificate=False, Server=http://xxxcom.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,774 WARN  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.AddIn.AddInManager: Failed to load type 'Spotfire.Dxp.Data.ActiveSpaces.ActiveSpacesAddIn, Spotfire.Dxp.Data.ActiveSpaces' from currently loaded assemblies.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,790 WARN  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.AddIn.AddInManager: Failed to load type 'Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.SapBw.SapBwAdapterAddIn, Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.SapBw.AddIn' from currently loaded assemblies.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,790 WARN  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.AddIn.AddInManager: Failed to load type 'Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.Essbase.EssbaseAdapterAddIn, Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.Essbase.AddIn' from currently loaded assemblies.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,790 WARN  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.AddIn.AddInManager: Failed to load type 'Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.Composite.CompositeAddIn, Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.Composite.AddIn' from currently loaded assemblies.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,806 WARN  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.AddIn.AddInManager: Failed to load type 'Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.MySql.MySqlAddIn, Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.MySql.AddIn' from currently loaded assemblies.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,806 WARN  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.AddIn.AddInManager: Failed to load type 'Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.Netezza.NetezzaAddIn, Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.Netezza.AddIn' from currently loaded assemblies.
2017-07-07 12:07:22,806 WARN  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.AddIn.AddInManager: Failed to load type 'Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.PostgreSql.PostgreSqlAdapterAddIn, Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Adapters.PostgreSql.AddIn' from currently loaded assemblies.
2017-07-07 12:07:23,008 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Services.ManifestReader: Downloading the manifest from 'http://gbbvl077.gb-cdc01.nxp.com/spotfire/manifest' took 155.999 milliseconds
2017-07-07 12:07:23,040 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.CoreApplication: Logging in
2017-07-07 12:07:26,581 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Application.AnalysisApplication: CurrentUICulture is en-US, server specifies en-US.
2017-07-07 12:07:26,612 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ASAutomationWorker.ASAutomationWorker: Parsing arguments
2017-07-07 12:07:26,659 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ASAutomationWorker.ASAutomationWorker: Job launched
2017-07-07 12:07:26,674 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ASAutomationWorker.ASAutomationWorker: Job File: 'F:\appl\tibco\Automation Services\6.5.0\Temp\6722dfba-f649-430a-a1dc-a11504e89628_job.xml' Status File: 'F:\appl\tibco\Automation Services\6.5.0\Temp\6722dfba-f649-430a-a1dc-a11504e89628_status.txt'
2017-07-07 12:07:26,674 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ASAutomationWorker.ASAutomationWorker: Loading job file.
2017-07-07 12:07:26,862 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ASAutomationWorker.ASAutomationWorker: Executing task 1 of 2: Open Analysis from Library
2017-07-07 12:07:45,191 WARN  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.NotificationService: Linked Data Report
There are some inconsistencies and some data might not be shown accurately.
Linked data table 'Basic IL - BW_OB08_VW24': 
Some columns matched, but not all.
Missing columns: Avg(NXP Standard Cost USD Real) for, Min(NXP Standard Cost USD) for
Linked data table 'Basic IL - BW_OB08_VW24': 
The following columns are no longer valid: costs in USD

2017-07-07 12:07:46,705 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ASAutomationWorker.ASAutomationWorker: Executing task 2 of 2: Send Email
2017-07-07 12:07:48,077 INFO  [6248,11] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ASAutomationWorker.ASAutomationWorker: Job finished successfully
2017-07-07 12:07:49,029 INFO  [6248,1] Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.Launcher.Program: Application End
```

Is this valid
[image: Screenshot for Automation Output 1]

[image: Screenshot for Automation Output 2]

Comment: It can be true, or the user don't have permission to the folder, or the folder wasn't added to the config as trusted path.  Check the data source of the dxp first.

Answer (score 0):

there seem to be issue with the new column data ,they might have data which is not expected.like numerical(integer) column start getting real data